# Change button image size in winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to make the Icon on a button smaller, but I can't figure out how.

[image]

The size of the image is grayed out.

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to resize the `Image` and then set it as the `Buttons`Image:

```
// where 'MyImage' is the Image to display on the Button
this.Button1.Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(MyImage, new Size(32,32)));
```